# How to create ActiveX's m_hWnd HWND while generating an object using InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, com, activex, atl, ole

Im using the following JS code to create a new ActiveX object

```
        var playerDiv = document.createElement("div");
        playerDiv.style.border = "1px solid red";
        var size = 200 + 20 * index;
        playerDiv.style.width = 200 + 20 * index + "px";
        playerDiv.style.height = 200 + 20 * index + "px";
        playerDiv.setAttribute("id", 'divPlayer' + index);
        var str = '<object id="player' + index + '" classid="CLSID:69A1BC06-C88F-4849-81E7-DB0AB0628819" width="' + size + '" height="' + size + '"></object>';       
        playerDiv.innerHTML = str;
        divViewPort.appendChild(playerDiv);
```

Whereas playerDiv is a simple DIV tag. my problem occurs during the innerHTML binding, during the binding procedure, a new activeX object is constructed but i dont receive calls from the JS engine to construct the m_hWnd variable. looking at the **legacy** code,
the call stack:

```
>   BCPlayer.dll!CSinglePlayer::CreateControlWindow(HWND__ * hWndParent, tagRECT & rcPos) Line 3207 C++
    BCPlayer.dll!ATL::CComControlBase::InPlaceActivate(long iVerb, const tagRECT * __formal) Line 1037  C++
    BCPlayer.dll!ATL::IOleObjectImpl<CSinglePlayer>::DoVerbInPlaceActivate(const tagRECT * prcPosRect, HWND__ * __formal) Line 2263 C++
    BCPlayer.dll!ATL::IOleObjectImpl<CSinglePlayer>::DoVerb(long iVerb, tagMSG * __formal, IOleClientSite * pActiveSite, long __formal, HWND__ * hwndParent, const tagRECT * lprcPosRect) Line 2363 C++
    mshtml.dll!COleSite::InPlaceActivate(struct IOleObject *,struct HWND__ *,struct tagMSG *)   Unknown
    mshtml.dll!COleSite::TransitionTo(enum OLE_SERVER_STATE,struct tagMSG *)    Unknown
    mshtml.dll!COleSite::TransitionToBaselineState(enum OLE_SERVER_STATE)   Unknown
    mshtml.dll!COleSite::EnterTree(void)    Unknown
    mshtml.dll!COleSite::Notify(class CNotification *)  Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CObjectElement::Notify(class CNotification *)    Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CSpliceTreeEngine::InsertSplice(void)    Unknown
    mshtml.dll!__chkstk()   Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CDoc::CutCopyMove(class CMarkupPointer *,class CMarkupPointer *,class CMarkupPointer *,int,unsigned long)    Unknown
    mshtml.dll!InjectHtmlStream(class CMarkupPointer *,class CMarkupPointer *,struct IStream *,unsigned long,class CElement *,enum INJECTION_FLAGS,class CElement *,enum ELEMENT_TAG,bool,unsigned int,enum CPSRCE) Unknown
    mshtml.dll!HandleHTMLInjection(class CMarkupPointer *,class CMarkupPointer *,unsigned short const *,long,class CElement *,enum INJECTION_FLAGS,class CElement *,enum ELEMENT_TAG)   Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CElement::InjectInternal(enum CElement::Where,unsigned short const *,long,enum INJECTION_FLAGS)  Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CElement::InjectTextOrHTML(enum CElement::Where,bool,unsigned short const * const,int)   Unknown
    mshtml.dll!CElement::put_innerHTML(unsigned short *)    Unknown
```

The following function:

```
CSinglePlayer::CreateControlWindow(HWND hWndParent, RECT& rcPos)
```

is an override of `public CComControl<CSinglePlayer>`.
which executes `CComControl<CSinglePlayer>::CreateControlWindow(hWndParent, rcPos);`

once we understood how the legacy code works, the innerHTML used on my object, never even gets to execute any of IOleObjectImpl functions, the only way i managed to simulate a working environment is by raising an OnClick() event which forced the JS to call the needed functions and generate the m_hWnd.
i've inherited the following interfaces / classes:

```
    class /*ATL_NO_VTABLE*/
__declspec(uuid("{69A1BC06-C88F-4849-81E7-DB0AB0628819}"))
VPlayer :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComMultiThreadModel>
    //, public ATL::CWindowImpl<VPlayer, ATL::CWindow, ATL::CFrameWinTraits>
    , public IObjectSafetyImpl<VPlayer, INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER |INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_DATA>
    , public CComCoClass<VPlayer, &__uuidof(VPlayer)>
    , public IDispatchImpl<IVPlayerControl>
    , public IDispatchImpl<IVPlayerSpeed>
    , public IDispatchImpl<IMetadata>
    , public IStreamingSourceCallback
    , public IPlayerEx
    , public CComControl<VPlayer>
    , public IOleControlImpl<VPlayer>
    , public IOleObjectImpl<VPlayer>
    , public IOleInPlaceActiveObjectImpl<VPlayer>
    , public IViewObjectExImpl<VPlayer>
    , public IOleInPlaceObjectWindowlessImpl<VPlayer>
    , public IQuickActivateImpl<VPlayer>
```

m_bWindowOnly = TRUE;

thanks

Comment: Rather than put_innerhtml, try creating the object element directly and explicitly add it to the DOM.  That will likely set the site correctly.

Comment: It didn't work, i still can't see any CreateWindow calls...

Comment: The more I look at your question, the less I understand the problem.  Is the issue that you're not getting a call to `IOleObject::DoVerb(OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE, ....)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using friend's advise, we came to the understanding that somehow, the .rgs file got changed.
the following snippet was missing:

```
        'TypeLib' = s '{02BED0E7-FD7C-49a5-A046-C1008BA2660B}'
        'MiscStatus' = s '0'
        {
        '1' = s '%OLEMISC%'
        }
```